# Migrating from ef core 2.2.6 to 3.1 getting issues when there are multiple includes

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I just migrated EF core 2.2.6 to 3.1 and i am getting timeout issue when more include statement are used like shown below :

```
  var z = await _context.PortfolioCompany
                                 .Include(x => x.val).ThenInclude(x => x.valft)
                                 .Include(x => x.val).ThenInclude(x => x.ipv)
                                 .Include(x => x.up)
                                 .Include(x => x.pcf)
                                 .Include(b => b.pcl)
                                 .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.DealCode.ToUpper() == dealCode.ToUpper(), cancellationToken);
```

Please suggest how this issue can be resolved. While using the same query in EF core 2.2.6 it worked fine but now i am getting timeout issue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes says that using multiple include statement it shows timeout error but not sure how to resolve this? this was not a problem with ef core 2.2.6

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @adam0101 Timeout as it is not able to get the data

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default settings in SQL Server, queries should be case-insensitive. Therefore, you should not need to use `.ToUpper()`. Also, doing so may prevent the query from using the proper indices. I assume there are proper indices on your `dealCode` column and the foreign keys? Try removing the `.ToUpper()` calls and see if your query runs faster.

**Update** Based on your link, it looks like the work-around is to break the query into multiple queries and stitch it together in memory as done here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18017#issuecomment-535763068

Comment: no i tried this but the issue is when you use multiple include in ef core 3.1 it creates an issue. Check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes

Comment: but how will i do that in my scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with large data structures, the first question to consider is "do I need all of this data?"  For instance, can you use `Select` to retrieve just the details from the relevant tables and let EF build a more suitable query rather than trying to pull back all columns from all associated tables?

How long did this query take to run in EF Core 2.2?

My suggestion would be to look at the associated tables to see which tables might contain a lot of columns or any particularly big columns. (MEMO, VARCHAR(Max), that sort of thing) If you selectively eliminate tables, is there a suspect that stands out as resulting in a large delay?

For example, if you were to exclude `.Include(x => x.pcf)` and everything loads without a timeout. You can post-fetch the PCF prior to using it by issuing:

```
_context.Entry(z).Reference(x => x.pcf).Load();
```

Though if this query is to return data to a view etc. I would strongly recommend creating a view model structure based on what the view needs and using `Select` to populate it rather than eager loading an entire entity graph. If you're instead looking to load an entity to apply updates, then I'd lean towards only eager-loading the most commonly updated tables, and letting EF lazy-load the rest if needed, or leveraging the `Load` method to fetch if needed.